# how to search a matrix for multiple values and return its row name?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrix, one is an `index` matrix (ncol=1, nrow=20,000), storing the values that I want to search for, the other matrix is a `data` matrix, storing a large dataset (ncol=1, nrow=5,000).

`index` matrix: (`water`, `meat`, `gas`.... are row names)

```
water    DFAFADFADF
meat     QEREQRQTQTQ
gas      FEQQFQEFQF
.
.
.
..
```

`data` matrix: (`Tom`, `Luis`, `Jerry`, `Vincent`, `Richard`... are row names)

```
Tom              dfqfqfAFADFADaveffefd
Luis             eqeqfqefAFADFADuouojoimoij
Jerry            dafadfe3321AFADFADfdeff
Vincent          e31413413qeffffff
Richard          121eefq3ffAFADFADfffqffqff
.
.
.
..
```

I want to find for each value in `index` matrix, which row(s) of `data` matrix CONTAIN(S) that string, and record its `data` matrix's row name and put it in the following columns (or in a single column but separated by ",") of that string's row in the `index` matrix.

For example, I want to have a loop and first take the value `"DFAFADFADF"` from index matrix and search for which rows in data matrix contains this string, so I found that Tom, Luis, Jerry, Richard in `data` matrix contains that string, so I update the `index` matrix to be

`index` matrix:

```
water    DFAFADFADF    Tom, Luis, Jerry, Richard
meat     QEREQRQTQTQ
gas      FEQQFQEFQF
.
.
.
..
```

And then I take the next value in `index` matrix, `QEREQRQTQTQ`, to search the `data` matrix again and then go back to update the `index` matrix again, until I finished the last row of the `index` matrix.

Can any one help with a loop?  I guess we may need a loop, using `for (....)`, but don't know how .

Comment: You may use `%in%` or `match`

Comment: Can you please give an example?  Many Thanks!  I am totally naive on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index <- data.frame(one = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL"))
rownames(index) <- c("water", "meat", "fruit", "bread")
data <- data.frame(one = c("ABCDEF", "DEFZMN", "MNOABC", "ZXCJKL"))
rownames(data) <- c("Tom", "Jerry", "Rob", "Nate")

results <- data.frame()
for (r in 1:nrow(index)) {
    index$results[r] <- list(rownames(data)[grep(index$one[r], data$one, ignore.case = T)])
    count <- length(unlist(index$results[r]))
    df <- data.frame(data_match = unlist(index$results[r]),
                     pattern = rep(index$one[r], times = count),
                     index_match = rep(rownames(index)[r], times = count))
    results <- rbind(results, df)
}
reshape2::dcast(results, index_match ~ data_match)
```

This will generate a `list()` in the column index$results, so you might need to call `unlist()` on it depending on how you want to handle that information downstream. Also in R you can have named vectors and in a case were you have one column data frame maybe you might just need a named character vector like this:

```
index <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
names(index) <- c("water", "meat", "fruit", "bread")
```

Might make the matching simpler for the next time.

Comment: Dear Nathan, Thank you so much for your great help!!!  It worked!!! But as you have mentioned, I had a problem to output the results of "index", because index$results is a list for every row in index matrix.  Is there a way for me to output this index matrix into a csv file?  Do I need to do something to convert the index$results to something to allow the write.table(index, file="index.csv",sep=",") to work?  Or do you have a better way to out put the "index" matrix?  Thank you so much for your great help!

Comment: I cobbled to together a work around for building an csv ready data frame. Not sure how to force into a multi column result format yet...

Comment: There has got to be a better way to do this, but I don't know it. Hope that solution can work for you

Comment: Sure!  Thanks Nathan, it is working!  I am trying to find a way to out put the index data frame with its 2nd column as a "list" vector.  Trying... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution:

```
row.names(data)[apply(data, 1, function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(y) y %in% c("DFAFADFADF", "QEREQRQTQTQ", "FEQQFQEFQF"))
}), ]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your solution.  Can you further clarify what the c("a", "b", 3) shoud be based on the example in my question?  And where did the y read from?  I am totally naive with coding.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those represent whatever values you're trying to identify in wash row. The apply(matrix, 1, function) function allows you to run a function using each row (1) or each column (2). More complex functions can be called with apply(matrix, 1, function(x) foo(foo2(x)). You can even specify another apply function. In this case I said that row x would be used as the object in a sapply() call and y would be the object (nth value of a row) used in the cross referencing value function.